# Play 2: Asynchronous Controllers vs HTTP threads

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, web, playframework, playframework-2.0

The [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaAsync) of the Play Framework 2 says that Play is build from bottom up asynchronous. Furthermore it implies that there is a fixed amount of threads in a so called "default execution context". They recommend to execute long running tasks outside this default execution context to make sure the application does not block.

At this point I do not understand what exactly the benefit of this model vs a HTTP-thread for each request is? They say to make it easier to scale and to better work under load, but I don't get why.

Comment: I also want to know this and couldn't find a definitive answer yet. One thing is that threads take a lot of system resources so to keep them limited is a good thing performance- and resources-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playframework uses the *evented model* instead of the traditional *threaded model*.

In the *threaded model* exists a large amounts of threads that handles the incoming requests. Servers that use this model have a lot of threads in a pool waiting for incoming requests, this implies the use of memory and also the problem of shared mutable state (threads share memory and resources this is a problem when you want to scale)

In the *evented model* exists a small amount of request-processing threads that communicate with each other through message passing. This paradigm is focused in asynchronous tasks and functional programming model.